# A counterexample in measure theory on $\sigma$-infinite spaces

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

Usually measure theory books include the following theorem (citing Proposition 5.1.3 in Cohn's measure theory book)

> Let $(X, \mathcal A , \mu )$ and $(Y, \mathcal B, \nu )$ be $\sigma$-finite measure spaces. If $E$ belongs to the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}\times\mathcal{B}$, then the function $x\mapsto\nu(E_x)$ is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable
>   and the function $y\mapsto\mu(E^y)$ is $\mathcal{B}$-measurable.

where $E_x=\{y\in Y\mid (x,y)\in E\}$ and $E^y=\{x\in X\mid (x,y)\in E\}$ are the slices of $E$. I'm looking for an example of two spaces (with at least one of them necessarily not $\sigma$-finite) for which this theorem fails.

I believe one of the two needs to be not only $\sigma$-infinite but also s-infinite. If this is not the case I would be very interested in an example involving an s-finite but not $\sigma$-finite space.

Comment: You will indeed need one of the measures to be s-infinite. The proof given by Cohn in fact shows the stronger fact that if $(Y,\mathcal{B},\nu)$ is an s-finite measure space and $(X, \mathcal{A})$ is a measurable space then for $E \in \mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{B}$, $x \mapsto \nu(E_x)$ is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable. He only uses $\sigma$-finiteness of $\nu$ to get s-finiteness of $\nu$ and he only requires a measure on both spaces to get a symmetric statement.

Comment: Indeed, that's precisely why I thought that s-infinite is enough, Cohn's proof only uses that a $\sigma$-finite measure is a sum of finite measures